# How to pass a vector of values as parameters for mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am writing a code which is expected to raise each column of a data frame to some exponent.

I've tried to use `mutate_all` to apply `function(x,a) x^a` to each column of the dataframe, but I am having trouble passing values of `a` from a pre-defined vector.

```r
powers <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(2,3,4), v3 = c(3,4,5))
df %>% mutate_all(.funs, ...)
```

I am seeking help on how to write the parameters of `mutate_all` so that the elements of `powers` can be applied to the function for each column.

I expect the output to be a data frame, with columns being `(1,2,3),(4,9,16),(27,64,125)` respectively.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `Map` in base R

```
df[] <- Map(`^`, df, powers)
```

Or `map2` in `purrr`

```
purrr::map2_df(df, powers, `^`)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the [] after df converting a list into a data frame?

Comment: @BoLiu yes, it maintains the same structure as the original `df`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `sweep()`from `base R`:

```
sweep(df, 2, powers, "^")

  v1 v2  v3
1  1  4  27
2  2  9  64
3  3 16 125
```

Comment: Really thanks on that! It works fine. What a pity that I never used sweep before!

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can replicate the 'powers' to make the lengths same and then apply the function

```
df ^ powers[col(df)]
#   v1 v2  v3
#1  1  4  27
#2  2  9  64
#3  3 16 125
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it's actually powered by row instead of by column

Comment: @BoLiu  It is to replicate the powers, i.e. each element of it is replicated based on the index given by `col`.  Please check the output